# Prove that : $16S^{2}+\left(a^{2}+c^{2}-b^{2}-d^{2}\right)^{2}=4e^{2}f^{2}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Problem : 
Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral sides : $a,b,c,d$ and $e,f$ sides of diagonal : 
Prove that :

> $$16S^{2}+\left(a^{2}+c^{2}-b^{2}-d^{2}\right)^{2}=4e^{2}f^{2}$$

Where :  $[ABCD]=S$ area

I don't know how I starte in this problem ? 
I'm thinking use $\operatorname{altitude}$

Comment: What does [ABCD] mean?

Comment: Its are sir ? $S=[ABCD]$ , $S$ here is area

Comment: S is the area of the quadrilateral ABCD?

Comment: Is this what you want https://www.fxsolver.com/browse/formulas/Coolidge%27s+formula+%28area+of+a+general+convex+quadrilateral%29

Comment: If you are familiar with cosine law, you can use it to simplify second term on the left hand side (apply theorem for all of the four triangles made by intersection of diagonals)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove area of a quadrilateral is $\frac14[4m^2n^2-(b^2+d^2-a^2-c^2)^2]^{\frac12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400526/prove-area-of-a-quadrilateral-is-frac144m2n2-b2d2-a2-c22-frac12)

Comment: Only one set of cases regardless of use can produce a different result parity wise.

Comment: @use2838619 thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Label the intersection of the diagonal $O$, and let $AO = p, BO = q, CO = r, DO = s, $ and angle $AOB = DOC = \theta. \ $ Note that angle $BOC = $ angle $DOA = 180 - \theta.$ I'm also labelling sides $AB$ as $a$, $BC \ b$, $CD \ c$, and $DA \ a$, for readability.

Using the cosine rule on triangles $AOB, \ BOC, \ DOC \ and \ DOA$ respectively, we get:
$$a^2 = p^2 + q^2 -2pq \ cos\theta \quad (1) \\
b^2 = q^2 + r^2 -2qr \ cos (180-\theta) \quad (2) \\
c^2 = r^2 + s^2 -2rs \ cos\theta \quad (3) \\
d^2 = p^2 + s^2 -2ps \ cos (180-\theta) \quad (4) \\ $$

Using the fact that  $cos (180-\theta) = - cos\theta, \ $  (1) + (3) - (2) - (4) then gives:

$a^2 + c^2 - b^2 - d^2 = -2(p+r)(q+s) \ cos\theta = -2ef cos\theta, \ $ and so

$(a^2 + c^2 - b^2 - d^2)^2 = 4e^2f^2 \ cos^2\theta \quad (5)$

Now, we can also write the area of ABCD using the Area Sine Law for each of the 4 triangles, and using the fact that $sin(180-\theta) = sin\theta , \ $ and after some further manipulation similar to above, we get:

$S = Area ABCD = \frac{1}{2}ef sin\theta, \ $ therefore:

$16S^2 = 4e^2f^2sin^2\theta \quad (6).$

$(5) + (6)$ gets the result.

Comment: thank you very much sir